# How to insert data using stored procedure after encrypted column using Always Encrypt option?

Tags: sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I am using sql server 2016 and i have encrypted the column using always encryption option. I have connected sql with entity frameworking in ASP.NET MVC application. The dats are inserting properly using insert option. But i cant able to insert using stored procedure via mvc application. I am getting the following error
I have followed the below article.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110564/WebControls/

How can we refresh the stored procedure to apply encryption?

**Error:**
"The parameter \"@name\" does not have the same encryption information as the one it was created with. Use sp_refresh_parameter_encryption to refresh the parameter encryption information for the module."

Answer (score 2):

The error message pretty self-explanatory in this case.
Since the encryption metadata has changed since the proc was created, you need to update it via running the sys.sp_refresh_parameter_encryption proc:

```
exec sys.sp_refresh_parameter_encryption 'SchemaName.ProcedureName'
```